# Oxidshop - Custom field on basket page

Tags: oxid

I am customising an instance of oxidshop installed on my local machine. I want to add a text field on first step of basket page. The field will save the value to a new column in oxorder page.

Any idea how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since order object is created after step 4, you will need to store user input somewhere.

I suggest using session.
Therefore you will need to redirect the "continue to the next step" button on basket page to a new function (which stores user input in session) in `user` controller by adding "fnc=myfunction" request parameter to the form being submitted:

```
<input type="hidden" name="fnc" value="myfunction"/>
```

After this value is stored in session, you will need to extend `oxOrder`function `_setUser()` and after calling `parent::_setUser()` you can save your session variable in oxorder:

`protected function _setUser ($oUser) {
    parent::_setUser($oUser);
    $this->assign(['oxorder__myvalue' => oxRegistry::getSession()->getVariable('myvalue')]);
}`

you will also need to remove "checkout" button in minibasket flyout/popup, because it skips the basket page and jumps right into step 2.

Comment: Thanks I think it should work. Will give a try. However, right now I am into another problems.

Comment: How do I extend this oxOrder controller function? Shall I add a new controller?

Comment: no, you extend oxOrder model with the code above, you do not need new controller.